# How to replace first instance of value in a list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list where i would like to replace first instance of 1 with 'xyz'.

```
list1 = list(
    x=c(1,2,3,1,2),
    y=c(-1,-2,1,2,1)
)
```

My expected op:

```
list1 = list(
    x=c('xyz',2,3,1,2),
    y=c(-1,-2,'xyz',2,1)
)
```

I can't use `ifelse` as it would replace all the instance of 1.

I tried finding the index. Then use `mapply`, but it doesn't work either.

```
list2=lapply(list1, function(x) which(x==1)[1])
mapply(function(x,y){x[y]='xyz'}, list1, list2)
```

How do we replace values in a list based on other list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to return the index of the first match to `replace` that position with 'xyz'

```
lapply(list1, function(x) replace(x, match(1, x, nomatch = 0), "xyz"))
#$x
#[1] "xyz" "2"   "3"   "1"   "2"  

#$y
#[1] "-1"  "-2"  "xyz" "2"   "1"
```

As it is a `list` of `vector`s, by changing numeric value with `character` changes the `class` to `character`

If we have two lists, i.e. one an index index, use `Map` or `mapply`

```
Map(function(x, y) replace(x, y, "xyz"), list1, list2)
```

Or in a more compact way

```
Map(`[<-`, list1, list2, "xyz")
#$x
#[1] "xyz" "2"   "3"   "1"   "2"  

#$y
#[1] "-1"  "-2"  "xyz" "2"   "1"
```

If the values to change would also be different, it can be a `vector` or `list` with the same length as the other `list`s

```
Map(`[<-`, list1, list2, c("xyz", "zyx"))
```

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli `Map` if wrapper for `mapply` I use `Map` because `mapply` deffault argument is `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` can coerce to matrix when the `list` elements have the same length or else,specify `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`

Comment: yeah i meant map solution

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli `map` is from `purrr`, and it would be `map2(list1, list2, ~ replace(.x, .y, "xyz"))`

Comment: I meant Map way not the purr(map). sorry for being vague.